# How can create more than one user class in parse

Tags: parse-platform

In our app we have multiple types of users ( caregiver ,patient)  each user must login to app then will view his homepage , how can implement this in parse.com ,Because it does not allow the creation  only for one user Class

Any help please !
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Roles feature which allows you to assign User privileges to specific users.

Read more about [Roles](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#roles/iOS) (this is the iOS doc)